# Davening to change nature

Tags: tefilla, talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot, talmud-yerushalmi

In Mashcehes Brachos (Bavli) 60 the Gemara states that one should not pray that his unborn baby be a boy if it's after the time the baby has formed already in the womb. However, in Masheches Brachos in the Yerushalmi perek 9:halacha 3 the Gemara brings the opinion of Rabbi Yehuda ben Pazi who holds one can daven for the baby to be a certain gender even while the mother is sitting on the birthing stool.

My question is that in Bavli the Gemara (Mishna) brings a case of a person who hears there is an outcry of anguish in their town and davens that its not coming from his family, the Mishna holds this is a prayer in vain. However, the Yerushalmi does not bring this case, so would Rabbi Yehuda ben Pazi allow one to pray in this case as well, or is an unborn baby the only unique case in which one can pray for a change in nature?

Comment: I doubt he would argue on a mishna. And there is a difference between changing a natural present state and changing what has already happened in the past which would require changing time- space(?). But +1. Nice question.

Comment: Well he argued on a Mishna already in regards to praying for the gender to be a male,its in the same mishna

Comment: Hhmm. You are probably right about that. I always assumed he was working with the mishna somehow. But anyways back to your question, even his wording only allows up until sitting on the birthing stone. I don't he would allow praying the next week, do you? But again, good question.

Comment: I hear what your saying about after birth but that can be seen with the eye,however, the town case he doesnt see whats going on ,and maybe supernaturally it wont be his family,it could be you have an answer just trying to get a clear understanding

Comment: So far on Rashi in Vayeitzei 30 21 I found that Re'em says R'Y'B'P' is in fact arguing on the mishna, assuming he found a braisa to rely upon. On the other hand Nachalas Yaakov has an explanation saying that is not necessarily so, but does seem to lean that way anyway. And here's possibly my final thought. The drasha R'Y'B'P' makes to prove his point is from Yirmiya 18 6 which is Hashem asserting He can do anything with Bnei Yisroel. The Malbim there explains the passuk to be reffering specificaly to a potter at the time of forming the vessel. Might help with your question.